# Optimize the split of a String from console

Tags: java, optimization

I have to read a `String` from console, so I used the `tokenizer` to split it and add each token in a position on `arrayList`, is there a way to improve the operation of split?

```
while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
            StringTokenizer string = new StringTokenizer(currentLine, " ");
            while (string.hasMoreTokens()) {
            arrayList.add(string.nextToken());
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not your bottleneck, but you could achieve the same result by:

- ditching the `StringTokenizer` in favour of `String.split()`
- replacing the `while` loop with a call to `Collections.addAll(T...)`

Like so:

```
while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    Collections.addAll(arrayList, currentLine.split(" ")));
}
```

The static method `Collections.addAll()` is preferable to `arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList())`:

> `public static <T> boolean addAll(Collection<? super T> c, T... elements)`
>
> Adds all of the specified elements to the specified collection. Elements to be added may be specified individually or as an array. The behavior of this convenience method is identical to that of `c.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements))`, but this method is likely to run significantly faster under most implementations.

Comment: I have my doubts whether this is more efficient since you first create a new `List<T>` after which `addAll()` translates this back into an array using `toArray()`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel good point, although [`asList` only creates a thin wrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) over the array. See the improved implementation above.